# How do I print out pandas dataframe in one single line in visual studio code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have converted my list of dictionaries into pandas dataframe by using the following code.

```
      pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
      pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```

However, the output is showing up like this instead of just one single line.

```
                                   Name                                      Description Activity Dates (Individual) Scheduled Days Scheduled Start Time Scheduled End Time Duration Allocated Location Name Allocated Staff Name Zone Name Module    Session
0    DICT-DNDFC_221_FT_DCNG_Lab01GrpA/1              Data Communication & Networking                   29/4/2021       Thursday
    12:00:00           15:00:00     3:00         Online Learning     Dr Thomas   Jackson   DDDD  Lab01GrpB
1    DICT-DNDFC_221_FT_DCNG_Lab01GrpB/1              Data Communication & Networking                    4/5/2021        Tuesday
    12:00:00           15:00:00     3:00         Online Learning     Dr Thomas   Jackson   DDDD  Lab01GrpB
2    DICT-DNDFC_221_FT_DCNG_Lab02GrpA/1              Data Communication & Networking                   18/5/2021        Tuesday
```

I want the output of the list of dictionaries to be organized with rows and columns.

Comment: You can use tabulate - https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried to use tabulate to display the data but the data is too cramped up.